# Unix shell script to spawn a command (unimrcp client) does not return

Tags: bash, unix, process, background, jobs

I have a very simple Unix script which spawns a unircpclient application.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
./unimrcpclient &                                                               
wait
```

The ./unimrcpclient should result in running the client and get the console of unimrcpclient application. It does that when I run the following from the command line.

```
./unimrcpclient & fg
```

However, when I try running the script with ./script.sh, where script.sh is as described above, it results in reading several characters from the terminal and inputting them to the unimrcpclient console. I saw the same behavior when I tried doing this using Python(system) and C (execvp(...)).

I think the issue is that the process (running unimrcp) is not controlling the terminal and the control is returned to the parent process which keeps on reading input from the terminal or from the logs of the server and treat them as commands for unimrcpclient console.

Do you think that's the case? If not, why does that happen?
How do I stop the process to input anything to unimrcpclient's console?

I would really appreciate your help.

Normal run results in following,
Sample output.

```
    ./unimrcpclient & fg
[1] 1902
./unimrcpclient
2018-10-24 17:25:37:980937 [NOTICE] UniMRCP Client [1.5.0]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981040 [INFO]   APR [1.5.2]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981058 [NOTICE] Create MRCP Client
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981088 [NOTICE] Open Config File [/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/unimrcpclient.xml]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981514 [INFO]   Set Property ip:127.0.0.1
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981543 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMU]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981552 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMA]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981560 [INFO]   Register Codec [L16]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981577 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechsynth]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechrecog]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981597 [NOTICE] Register Resource [recorder]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981606 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speakverify]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981613 [INFO]   Register Resource Factory
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981628 [NOTICE] Create SofiaSIP Agent [SIP-Agent-1] [1.12.11-227-g73efc97] sip:127.0.0.1:8062;transport=udp
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981641 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [SIP-Agent-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981654 [NOTICE] Create RTSP Client [RTSP-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981689 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [RTSP-Agent-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981722 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv2 Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981745 [INFO]   Register Connection Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981756 [NOTICE] Create Media Engine [Media-Engine-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981768 [INFO]   Register Media Engine [Media-Engine-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981777 [NOTICE] Create RTP Termination Factory 127.0.0.1:[4000,5000]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981785 [INFO]   Register RTP Termination Factory [RTP-Factory-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981796 [INFO]   Register RTP Settings [RTP-Settings-1]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981804 [INFO]   Enter Directory [/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/client-profiles]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981841 [NOTICE] Open Config File [/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/client-profiles/unimrcp.xml]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981939 [INFO]   Create SIP Settings 127.0.0.1:8060
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981959 [INFO]   Register Signaling Settings [UniMRCP-SIP-Settings]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981970 [INFO]   Create RTSP Settings 127.0.0.1:1554
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981977 [INFO]   Register Signaling Settings [UniMRCP-RTSP-Settings]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:981992 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv2 Profile [uni2]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:982016 [INFO]   Register Profile [uni2]
2018-10-24 17:25:37:982025 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv1 Profile [uni1]
```

With script I get the following, (unknown command)

```
./script.sh

2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Set Property ip:127.0.0.1
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMU]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [PCMA]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [INFO]   Register Codec [L16]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechsynth]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:618851 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speechrecog]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [recorder]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620588 [NOTICE] Register Resource [speakverify]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620593 [INFO]   Register Resource Factory
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create SofiaSIP Agent [SIP-Agent-1] [1.12.11-227-g73efc97] sip:127.0.0.1:8062;transport=udp
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [SIP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create RTSP Client [RTSP-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Signaling Agent [RTSP-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create MRCPv2 Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1] [100]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [INFO]   Register Connection Agent [MRCPv2-Agent-1]
2018-10-23 14:36:53:620600 [NOTICE] Create Media Engine [Media-Engine-1]
unknown command: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```